# Coproduct of two modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, category-theory

Suppose that $M$ is an $A$-module, and $N$ is a $B$-module. The coproduct of $A$ and $B$ is $A\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}B$, and the coproduct of $M$ and $N$ is $M\oplus N$. I was wondering if $M\oplus N$ could be a module over $A\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}B$, so that it is a "coproduct of two modules." But it appears that there is no $A\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}B$-module structure on $M\oplus N$. Is it true that "the category of modules" doesn't have coproducts?

Edit: All rings are assumed to be commutative. I'm envisaging a "category of modules," where  objects are pairs $(A,M)$, where $A$ is a ring and $M$ is an abelian group, together with $A$-scalar multiplication structure. A morphism $(A,M)→(B,N)$ is a pair $(f,ϕ)$, where $f:A→B$ is a ring homomorphism, $ϕ:M→N$ is an abelian group homomorphism, such that $ϕ(am)=f(a)ϕ(m)$. 
When I said "coproduct of $M$ and $N$", I'm treating them as abelian groups.

The question is whether this category has coproducts. My initial guess was that the coproduct of $(A,M)$ and $(B,N)$ is $(A\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}B,M\oplus N)$. I think this is wrong, but I think a more complicated coproduct exists for any family of modules $(A_\alpha,M_\alpha)_\alpha$. My current guess looks something like $(\varinjlim\otimes A_\alpha,\varinjlim\otimes_{\beta\neq\alpha}A_\beta\otimes M_\alpha)$.

Comment: You said "and the coproduct of $M$ and $N$ is $M\oplus N$."
while you asked "Is it true that "the category of modules" doesn't have coproducts?" I don't think you make sense.

Comment: I'm envisaging the "category of modules," where the objects are pairs $(A,M)$, where $A$ is a ring and $M$ is an abelian group, together with $A$-scalar multiplication structure. When I said "coproduct of $M$ and $N$", I'm treating them as abelian groups.

Comment: What are the morphisms?

Comment: A morphism $(A,M)\rightarrow(B,N)$ is a pair $(f,\phi)$, where $f:A\rightarrow B$ is a ring homomorphism, $\phi:M\rightarrow N$ is an abelian group homomorphism, such that $\phi(am)=f(a)\phi(m)$.

Comment: I suggest you rewrite your question. Nobody can read your mind.

Comment: I think the main source of confusion is that by a "module," I'm referring to the pair $(A,M)$, rather than $M$ alone, which is the usual convention. I call $(A,M)$ a "module," and $M$ an $A$-module.

Comment: Well, edit the question to remove any possibility of confusion! (You seem to be assuming that the rings are commutative: being explicit about that too never hurts, either)

Comment: The total category of modules is a Grothendieck opfibration over the category of rings, and there is a procedure to construct colimits in such things out of colimits in the base and colimits in the fibres. I think the coproduct you're thinking of is actually $(B \otimes_\mathbb{Z} M) \oplus (A \otimes_\mathbb{Z} N)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\dlim}{\varinjlim}
\newcommand{\sst}{\subset}
\newcommand{\sbe}{_\beta}
\newcommand{\sal}{_\alpha}
\newcommand{\iso}{isomorphism}
\newcommand{\al}{\alpha}
\newcommand{\be}{\beta}
\newcommand{\fall}{\ \ \forall}
\newcommand{\dra}{\dashrightarrow}
\newcommand{\mt}{\mapsto}
\newcommand{\ra}{\rightarrow}
\newcommand{\cc}{\circ}
\newcommand{\id}{\operatorname{id}}
\newcommand{\itk}[1]{{\it #1}}
\newcommand{\ras}{\overset{\sim}{\ra}}
\newcommand{\amod}{$A$-module}
\newcommand{\Hom}{\operatorname{Hom}}
\newcommand{\ten}{\otimes}
\newcommand{\opl}{\oplus}
\newcommand{\rf}[1]{\overset{#1}{\rightarrow}}
\newcommand{\ifof}{if and only if }
\newcommand{\la}{\leftarrow}
\newcommand{\Ra}{\Rightarrow}
\newcommand{\set}[1]{\left\{ #1 \right\}}
\newcommand{\setst}[2]{\left\{ #1 \ | \ #2 \right\}}
\newcommand{\lf}[1]{\overset{#1}{\leftarrow}}
\newcommand{\lff}[1]{\overset{#1}{\longleftarrow}}
\newcommand{\im}{\operatorname{im}}
\newcommand{\sur}{\twoheadrightarrow}
\newcommand{\krn}{\operatorname{ker}}
\newcommand{\hra}{\hookrightarrow}
\newcommand{\las}{\overset{\sim}{\la}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\bb}{\backslash}
\newcommand{\os}[2]{\overset{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\us}[2]{\underset{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\amods}{$A$-modules}
\newcommand{\sm}{\smallskip}
\newcommand{\beq}[1]{\begin{equation}#1\end{equation}}
\newcommand{\ffall}{\qquad\forall}
\newcommand{\del}{\delta}
\newcommand{\isos}{isomorphisms}
\newcommand{\Tcd}{There is a commutative diagram}
\newcommand{\cd}{commutative diagram}
\newcommand{\tcd}{there is a \cd}
\newcommand{\tis}{there is an \iso}
\newcommand{\Tis}{There is an \iso}
\newcommand{\gam}{\gamma}
\newcommand{\hmms}{homomorphisms}
\newcommand{\Del}{\Delta}
\newcommand{\fgas}{f.g.~\amods}
\newcommand{\lam}{\lambda}
\newcommand{\Tesq}{There is an exact sequence}
\newcommand{\isoc}{isomorphic}
\newcommand{\bopl}{\bigoplus}
\newcommand{\wrt}{with respect to}
\newcommand{\esqs}{exact sequences}
\newcommand{\qqq}{\qquad\quad}
\newcommand{\ds}{_*}
\newcommand{\dla}{\dashleftarrow}
\newcommand{\sab}{_{\al\be}}
\newcommand{\sx}{_x}
\newcommand{\Calg}{\mathsf{Alg}}
\newcommand{\Cab}{\mathsf{Ab}}
\newcommand{\ang}[1]{\langle #1\rangle}
\newcommand{\hpsi}{\hat{\psi}}
\newcommand{\hphi}{\hat{\phi}}
\newcommand{\resp}{respectively}
\newcommand{\cds}{commutative diagrams}
\newcommand{\qq}{\qquad}
\newcommand{\mf}{\mapsfrom}
\newcommand{\aalg}{$A$-algebra}
\newcommand{\aalgs}{$A$-algebras}
\newcommand{\Cring}{\mathsf{Ring}}
\newcommand{\Cmod}{\mathsf{Mod}}
\newcommand{\alg}{algebra}
\newcommand{\algs}{algebras}
\newcommand{\hmm}{homomorphism}$

**Proposition.** The category $\Cmod$ has coproducts.

**Proof.** Let $(A\sal,M\sal)_{\al\in\Lambda}$ be a nonempty family in $\Cmod$.  Let $A'$ be the direct limit of finite tensor products of $(A\sal)\sal$, i.e., $A'=\dlim\ten_{\al\in I}A\sal$, where $I\sst\Lambda$ is a finite subset. Given $\al\in\Lambda$, let $A'\sal:=\dlim\ten_{\be\in I\sal}A\sbe$, where $I\sal\sst\Lambda\bb\set{\al}$ is a finite subset. We claim that $A'\simeq A\sal\ten A'\sal\fall\al\in\Lambda$. To see this, first note that for every $\al\in\Lambda$, there is an obvious ring \hmm\ $\tau'\sal:A'\sal\dra A'$.
This induces a ring \hmm
$$\phi:A\sal\ten A'\sal\dra A',\qqq a\sal\ten x\mt\tau_{\set{\al}}(a\sal)\tau'\sal(x),$$
where $(\tau_I)_{I\sst\Lambda}$ is the direct limit for $A'$.

On the other hand, let $(\sigma_{I\sal})_{I\sal}$ be the direct limit for $A'\sal$.
Given a finite subset $I\sst\Lambda$, define a  ring \hmm
$$\psi_I:A\sal\ten A'\sal\la \ten_{\al\in I}A\sal$$
as follows: if $\al\not\in I$, then $\psi_I(x):=1_{A\sal}\ten\sigma_I(x)$. If $\al\in I$, then 
$$\psi_I(\ten_{\be\in I}a\sbe)=a\sal\ten\sigma_{I'\sal}(\ten_{\be\in I'\sal}a\sbe),$$
where $I'\sal:=I\bb\set{\al}$. It is easy to see that $\psi_I$ is compatible with inclusions of the finite subsets $I$. Hence, there is an induced ring \hmm
$$\hpsi:A\sal\ten A'\sal\dla A'.$$
It is easy to see that $\phi$ and $\hpsi$ are inverses of each other.

Now let $M'\sal:=M\sal\ten A'\sal$. It is then an $A'$-module, and we will show that $(A',\opl\sal M'\sal)$ is the coproduct of $(A\sal,M\sal)\sal$.

There is an abelian group \hmm
$$j\sal:M\sal\ra M'\sal,\qqq m\sal\mt m\sal\ten1'\sal.$$
Let $(i\sal)\sal$ be the coproduct for $\opl\sal M'\sal$. It is easy to see that
$$(\tau_{\set{\al}},i\sal\cc j\sal):(A\sal,M\sal)\dra(A',\opl\sal M'\sal)$$
is a morphism in $\Cmod$.

Let $(\phi\sal,\psi\sal)\sal$ be a family of morphisms in $\Cmod$, where 
$$(\phi\sal,\psi\sal):(A\sal,M\sal)\ra(B,N).$$
Then there are induced ring \hmms\ $\hphi:A'\dra B$, $\hphi\sal:A'\sal\dra B$, and a unique abelian group \hmm
$$\hpsi\sal:M'\sal\dra N$$
\st $m\sal\ten x\mt\hphi\sal(x)\cdot\psi\sal(m\sal)$. Note that $\hpsi\sal\cc j\sal=\psi\sal$.
It is easy to see that
$$(\hphi,\hpsi\sal):(A',M'\sal)\ra(B,N)$$
is a morphism of modules, so there is an induced morphism of modules
$$(\hphi,\hpsi):(A',\opl\sal M'\sal)\dra(B,N).$$
It is easy to see that $\hpsi\sal$ is the unique abelian group \hmm\ \st for every $\al\in\Lambda$, $\hpsi\sal\cc j\sal=\psi\sal$ and $(\hphi,\hpsi\sal)$ is a morphism of modules. Hence, the uniqueness of $(\hphi,\hpsi)$ follows.

Comment: What \hmm\ is supposed to mean? And \st?

Answer (score 1):

The natural way to write down an $A \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} B$-module from this data is to actually take the tensor product $M \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} N$. This follows from a careful inspection of the universal property of the tensor product.

$M \oplus N$ instead inherits an action of $A \oplus B$. The motivating example here is when $M, N$ are two finite-dimensional vector spaces $V, W$ and $A = \text{End}(V), \text{End}(W)$.

Comment: But I can't think of an abelian group homomorphism $M\rightarrow M\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}N$. I'm thinking of maybe $(M\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}B)\oplus(A\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}N)$. If $(f,\phi):(A,M)\rightarrow(C,L)$, $(g,\psi):(B,N)\rightarrow(C,L)$ are morphisms of modules, then the induced morphism will be $(A\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}B,(M\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}B)\oplus(A\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}N))\rightarrow(C,L),\quad(a\otimes b,m\otimes n)\mapsto g(b)\phi(m)+f(a)\psi(n)$.

Comment: Why do you want an abelian group homomorphism $M \to M \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} N$?

Comment: If $(A\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}B,M\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}N)$ is a coproduct of $(A,M)$ and $(B,N)$, we need morphisms $(f,\phi):(A,M)\rightarrow(A\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}B,M\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}N)$ and $(g,\psi):(B,N)\rightarrow(A\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}B,M\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}N)$ in the category of modules.

Comment: @ashpool: in the first version of your question it was not clear that you wanted to construct coproducts in the "category of modules" (this is a confusing name).

Comment: Writing latex without preview is a nightmare! Here is a correction to my first comment: $(a\otimes b,m\otimes n)\mapsto(f(a)g(b),g(b)\phi(m)+f(a)\psi(n))$.